# How to scroll to end of System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, browser

How can you scroll to the end of a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser programmatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ctlWebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false);
```

The boolean parameter for ScrollIntoView() is true to align the scrollbar with the top of the document, and false to align the scrollbar with the bottom of the document.

MSDN documentation here: [HtmlElement.ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview.aspx)

Comment: But remember, that HTML loaded into `WebBrowser` needs to contain `Body` tag. And if you would like to do it right after the contents was loaded to the `WebBrowser` instance, the best is to use `Navigated` event, for example:  webBrowser1.Navigated += (s1, e1) => { if (webBrowser1.Document.Body != null) webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false); };

Answer (score 15):

I'm setting `DocumentText` property of the `WebBrowser` control (with html and body tags) and `Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false)` method didn't worked for me, but this is working:

```
    private void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        // MOST IMPORTANT : processes all windows messages queue
        Application.DoEvents();

        if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height);
        }
    }
```

source: http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/webbrowsercontrol-scroll-to-bottom/

Comment: reminder: see the "MOST IMPORTANT" part... need to let WinForms DoEvents before this will work

Answer (score 1):

When I had no ending *body* element, this worked for me (VB.NET):

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.All(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.All.Count - 1).ScrollIntoView(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wb1.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to user2349661's answer this is the same for C#:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.All[WebBrowser1.Document.Body.All.Count -1].ScrollIntoView(False)
```

n.b. would have added as a comment but I don't have enough points!

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript creates ie security problems

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(...);")
```

It is better to use a direct call like

```
webBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a Document Completed event would be a good option:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990651/how-to-scroll-to-end-of-system-windows-forms-webbrowser");

}


private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;

browser.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false);

}
```